# Can't drop a certain row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

note that title is index.

| title | rating | rat_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'Til There Was You | 2.333333 | 9 |
| 1-900 | 2.600000 | 5 |
| 101 Dalmatians | 2.908257 | 109 |
| 12 Angry Men | 4.344000 | 125 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Young Guns | 3.207921 | 101 |

I tried

```py
i = movies[movies['rating']==3.4444].index
movies.drop(i)
# This one has no effect and didn't removed
```

2:

```py
movies.drop(0)
```

3:

```
movies.drop(movies.iloc[0])
```

error of 3:

```
KeyError: '[3.4444444444444446, 9.0] not found in axis'
```

4:

```
movies.drop(' ')
```

error of 4:

```
KeyError: "[' '] not found in axis"
```

5:

```
movies.drop(' ',axis=0)
```

error of 5:

```
KeyError: "[' '] not found in axis"
```

I want to drop the first row, which has no title(or a blank) with 3.44 rating and 9 rat_count.

Comment: Please, include a minimal reproducible example. In your case, what is mainly missing is a dataframe (the one you provided is unreadable. And it would be easier for us to help you if you provided it in a python form: ``df = pd.DataFrame([[...]])``

Comment: Please consider updating the question to [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) even though you have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
movies.drop(movies.index[0])
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Good. It would be nice for future reader that you provide that dataframe example (tho I edited your post to that the dataframe is readable). Besides, I think it's worth mentioning that it is never a good idea to try to match floating point values. Not just with pandas. With computers in general. `==` should almost never be used anywhere near floating point numbers. Because `3.4444 != 3.44439999999999`. And you never know what can make two identical floats to be strictly speaking different (for example `(3.4444*10/10)==3.4444` is False. So, you should match rating with a tolerance.

Comment: For example you could ``df.drop(df[(df.rating-3.4444)**2<0.0001].index)``